# How to show hierarchial data in a dropdownlist

Tags: .net, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL Server 2005.

[alt text http://www.techpint.com/sites/default/files/images/table.JPG](http://www.techpint.com/sites/default/files/images/table.JPG)

I want to show all domain name in a dropdownlist maintaing the same hierarchy. i.e

> Law
>   Engineering 
>   --civil
>   --Mechanical
>   Medical
>   --Dental
>   ----Cavity
>   --MBBS

I need to append '--' according to the domain level. Is it possible using a sql query.
or alternatively can I have any other control to show this data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server 2005 and up, you can use recursive CTEs (example based on [this article](http://consultingblogs.emc.com/christianwade/archive/2006/09/20/SQL-Server-Standard-_2D00_-Recursive-Hierarchies-to-XML.aspx)):

```
DECLARE @t AS TABLE (domainid INT NOT NULL, domainname VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL, parentdomainid INT NULL);
INSERT INTO @t VALUES (1, 'Law', NULL);
INSERT INTO @t VALUES (3, 'Engineering', NULL);
INSERT INTO @t VALUES (4, 'Medical', NULL);
INSERT INTO @t VALUES (6, 'Civil', 3);
INSERT INTO @t VALUES (7, 'Mechanical', 3);
INSERT INTO @t VALUES (8, 'Dental', 4);
INSERT INTO @t VALUES (9, 'MBBS', 4);
INSERT INTO @t VALUES (12, 'Cavity', 8);

-- SELECT * FROM @t;

WITH CTE(domainid, parentdomainid, domainname, Depth, SortCol)
            AS
            (
              SELECT domainid, parentdomainid, domainname, 0, CAST(domainid AS varbinary(max))
              FROM @t
              WHERE parentdomainid IS NULL
              UNION ALL
              SELECT d.domainid, d.parentdomainid, d.domainname, p.Depth + 1,
                        CAST(SortCol + CAST(d.domainid AS binary(4)) AS varbinary(max))
              FROM @t AS d
                        JOIN CTE AS p
                          ON d.parentdomainid = p.domainid
            )
            SELECT domainid, parentdomainid, domainname, Depth, REPLICATE('--', Depth) + domainname as displayname
            FROM CTE
            ORDER BY SortCol;
```

Comment: @Cade Roux: Thanks for the query, Can you please let me know what is the role of SortCol here.

Comment: @vaibhav Have a look at it without the ORDER BY.  Without an ORDER BY, you are not guaranteed any particular order.  If you add SortCol to the SELECT, you can see what it's doing.  It just uses a fixed width hex representation to make the sorting correct.  If you weren't padding the concatenated numbers at all (say, in decimal form, with simple concatenation), 1,21 would be 121 and 12,1 would be 121 and, needless to say, the sorting would be a mess.

Answer (score 1):

1) you need to write a query to select all nodes with it's level (Name, Level)
2) convert level to a number of '-' and concatenate with Name string

A query (I know about WITH) to select DomainID, Level

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [GetDomainTree]
(
@topDomainID int
) with encryption
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @level int
DECLARE @count int

DECLARE @tempTable TABLE (DomainID int, [Level] int)

INSERT INTO @tempTable
(DomainID, [Level])
VALUES
(@topDomainID, 0)
SET @count = 1
SET @level = 0
WHILE @count > 0
 BEGIN
  INSERT INTO @tempTable
  (DomainID, [Level] )
  (
   SELECT DomainsRealTable.DomainID,
       @level + 1,
     @topDomainID
   FROM  @tempTable domains, DomainsRealTable
   WHERE domains.[Level] = @level
      AND DomainsRealTable.ParentDomainID = domains.DomainID
  )
  SELECT @count = COUNT(*)
  FROM   @tempTable
  WHERE  [Level] = @level + 1
  SET @level = @level + 1
 END
SELECT *
FROM   @tempTable
ORDER BY [Level]
END
```

Now, You can write a sql function which will take int parameter (level) and return nvarchar '-'*Level  and combine both queries to get the result you are want

Comment: @Nagg: What is level? Can you write a query.

Comment: take a query, but it may contains some mistakes :)

Answer (score 0):

you can also write it in code

psudo code, you get the idea

```
function createlist(parent_id, indent)
{
  if parent_id is null
  {
    select children_name, children_id from table where parent is null
  }
  else
  {
    indent += "--";
    select children_name, children_id from table where parent = parent_id
  }

  foreach result
  {
    write option value="children_id" +indent+children_name+ /option
    createlist(children_id, indent)
  }
}

createlist(null, "");
```

regardes

James Lin (guanfenglin@gmail.com)